# Remove a worksheet in Excel using r package xlsx

Tags: r, excel

As the title stated, I would like to delete the second worksheet in excel using r with package xlsx. However, after running the code, nothing happened. Following is a sample code I used to delete the sheet:

```
path = "C://ECOS//Code//Test//data.xlsx"
sheets = getSheets(loadWorkbook(path))
removeSheet(loadWorkbook(path), sheetName = names(sheets[2]))
```

Really appreciate helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to save the workbook in the same file (or different if you prefer).

```r
wb = loadWorkbook(path)
removeSheet(wb, sheetName = names(sheets[2]))
saveWorkbook(wb, path)
```

Comment: Is there a way to rename a sheet using the xlsx package?