# Error in replacing data in existing excel report in R

Tags: r

I am using the following function to save an excel sheet from R in an existing excel workbook replacing this same sheet, that is, I have an excel workbook with several sheets of it with the name Deposits and I want to export the df from R in excel keeping it in the same free and replacing the Deposits sheet

```
write.xlsx2 (uno, file = "//152.55.212.58/compartida/Insumo/Prueba.xlsx",
 sheetName = "Deposits", append = TRUE, row.names = False)
```

However, I registered the following error:

> ```
> Error in .jcall (wb, "Lorg / apache / poi / ss / usermodel / Sheet;", "createSheet" ,:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet with this name
> ```

the error appears with any file size, large or small, has anyone had a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would recommend to use a fake path or IP address in your questions, as a hacker may try to exploit knowledge of your IP address if you post it in your questions (DDoS, attack a vulnerable version of software that your question mentions, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the existing sheet, then save your new copy in its place:

```
path <- "//x.x.x.x/compartida/Insumo/Prueba.xlsx"
removeSheet(uno, sheetName = names("Deposits"))
write.xlsx2 (uno, file = path,
  sheetName = "Deposits", append = TRUE, row.names = False)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230675/remove-a-worksheet-in-excel-using-r-package-xlsx#34231101). A best practice would be to backup the existing workbook before you do so, in case there are any errors in your new version.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when trying to load the path of the excel workbook I now get the following error filenotfoundexception (Java) 
but the route is the right one